# Logged In User On Client showing to Other Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, openid

I have three pages: Login.aspx, Index.aspx and a C# class file named GlobalData.cs

The code behind the Login.aspx to get user information from google and to display on the Index.aspx

Here is Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty;
using OpenIdTest;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Extensions.SimpleRegistration;
using System.Web.Security;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Extensions.AttributeExchange;  

public partial class Account_Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FuncOpenID();

    }

    protected void FuncOpenID()
    {
        OpenIdRelyingParty OIDRP = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
        var response = OIDRP.GetResponse();
        if (response != null)
        {
            switch (response.Status)
            {
                case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:

                    var fetchResponse = response.GetExtension<FetchResponse>();
                    Session["GoogleIdentifier"] = fetchResponse;
                    var Testresponse = Session["GoogleIdentifier"] as FetchResponse;

                    GlobalData.Email = Testresponse.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email) ;
                    GlobalData.Name = Testresponse.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Name.First) ;
                    GlobalData.LastName = Testresponse.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Name.Last); 
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(GlobalData.Email, false);   //(response.ClaimedIdentifier, false);
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(GlobalData.Name, false);
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(GlobalData.LastName, false); 
                    break;
                case AuthenticationStatus.Canceled:

                    break;
                case AuthenticationStatus.Failed:

                    break;
            }
        }
    }



    protected void OpenLogin_Click(object src, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string StrUri = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
        var b = new UriBuilder(Request.Url) { Query = "" };

        var req = openid.CreateRequest(StrUri);

        var fetchRequest = new FetchRequest();
        fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
        fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.First);
        fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.Last);

        req.AddExtension(fetchRequest);

        req.RedirectToProvider();

    }
    protected void btnLoginToGoogle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```

**Update**
And the code behind the class file is below:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

    namespace OpenIdTest
    {
        public class GlobalData
        {
            public  string Email = "";
            public  string Name = "";
            public  string LastName = "";
            public  string test = "";
            public  string FullName = "";

        }
```

And the code behind the Index.aspx is below:

```
namespace OpenIdTest
{

public partial class Rights : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Session["U_EMAIL"] = GlobalData.Email;
        Session["U_NAME"] = GlobalData.Name;
        Session["U_LASTNAME"] = GlobalData.LastName;   


        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|OID.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;");

        con.Open(); 
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from EMAILS WHERE FLAG='Allowed' and  EMAIL= '" + GlobalData.Email + "'";

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {

          String email = row["EMAIL"].ToString();
          if (email == null)
          {
              Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");

          }
          else
          {
              Label2.Text = Session["U_EMAIL"].ToString();
              Label1.Text = Session["U_NAME"].ToString();
              Label3.Text = Session["U_LASTNAME"].ToString();
              Label1.Visible = false;
              Label3.Visible = false;
              Label4.Text = Label1.Text + ' ' + Label3.Text;

          }

        }
        con.Close(); 
    }



}
}
```

Now I am writing my serious Issue which i am facing.My Mechanism for my webpage for using openid is that when user Click on Login button on Login.aspx it takes the user to google mail after authenticating from google the user come back to the Index.aspx.And Here on INdex.aspx I have reauthenticate the user from mY own DB that if the email which google have  returned exists in My DB then the user should view the page and if the email dnt Exist in DB then user Redirects to the Login.aspx.Ok Now problem is that When I logged into Index.aspx after authenticating from both Google and My Own DB the Index.aspx Shows accurate information like email Fullname etc On Index.aspx.and mean while if I login to Index.aspx from anyother Browser or PC or Session then also user logged into Index.aspx Succesfuly.And When I refresh the First Logged Index.aspx then It displays the Second logged in user information on Current Index.aspx page.It mean when Multiple users are trying to Login into Index.aspx then On each refresh the on Index.aspx dispalys the Information of last user login to Index.aspx on Index.aspx.Can Anyone tell me What exactly I am Missing Thats why this issue is Displaying.I have Put My all code of allpages please help what i have to add in code or remove from code

Comment: Why are you using static fields in the first place? When developing web applications (regardless of underlying technology), everything user related should be stored in the respective user's session to prevent ugly bugs like the one described here. Static fields have also the disadvantage of possible deletion when the webserver decides to start a new process instead of reusing the old one (after it shut down the old one for not being accessed in a while, for example)

Comment: Why don't you look a little into ASP.NET Session variables and try yourself? I'd be glad to help if there are more problems in the future, but that doesn't mean that I'll do your work for you (and you have to learn it either way, if you want to continue writing ASP.NET apps which need to be capable of simultaneous multi user access).

Comment: Sessions variables are only useful, if you set them _when the session starts_, in other words: Once the user logged in. Since you initialize them just before actually using them from the same global variables you used before, there isn't any change.

Comment: No, you have to use the session variables _instead of_ `GlobalData`.

Comment: Sir if U See My Update I used them in Index.aspx But the Situation is Same that last logged in user Information is Displayed when Page is Refresh

Comment: It won't work as long as you use the `GlobalData` class _at all_. Delete it (the class definition), fix the compiler errors by replacing every reference to it by using an appropriate session variable and you should be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information stored at a user level can never be stored in a static.  A static property essentially means only one user will ever log into your site, and it will be the information of the last person who logged in.  Change your code to store those values in session, and then this problem will go away.

EDIT: It's hard to tell what's going on, but this still looks like a static, so you need to replace this:

```
GlobalData.Email = Testresponse.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email) ;
GlobalData.Name = Testresponse.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Name.First) ;
GlobalData.LastName = Testresponse.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Name.Last);
```

With this:

```
Session["U_Email"] = Testresponse.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email) ;
Session["U_Name"] = Testresponse.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Name.First) ;
Session["U_LastName"] = Testresponse.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Name.Last);
```

Because again, you can't use GlobalData since it's a static.

Comment: the problem description urgently needs an edit ... seems like he translated from google and pasted it, i was in the middle of an edit when you posted a solution

Comment: Any ONe can tell me HOw and Where to use Session Variables to do Resolve my PRoblem

Comment: AnyOne Please Check My Update I Have Removed Static from Class and used session variable to store the user Information But Situation is same

Comment: YES ITS WORKING NOW THANKS A LOT Brian Mains AND STACK AS WELL